# Python 3 type hint for re.finditer

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, type-hinting

I am very new to type hinting in Python 3, and have tried reading and understanding the PEP, and I'm struggling with this.

I have a function that returns the iterator from re.finditer()

```
def get_collected_issues(book: Book) -> Iterator:
    """Parse the 'collecting' part of the book description, for series names and issue details.
    """
    collecting = get_collecting(book)
    return re.finditer(FULL_REGEX, collecting, re.IGNORECASE)
```

When inspecting at runtime, each iteration of finditer() is a `_sre.SRE_Match` object, but that's not importable, so I'm not sure how I can make the return type hint any more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typing.re.Match` was added for exactly this reason.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.re